# python process._sbootstrap() / .start()

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, bootstrapping

How does python's multiprocessing.Process's start() method work. In particular, is there any documentation for Process._bootstrap() & if so where?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the source?

Comment: Yes - sorry - that's the obvious & corerct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code, straight from my Python 2.7 install:

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process

    try:
        self._children = set()
        self._counter = itertools.count(1)
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
            sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)
        except (OSError, ValueError):
            pass
        _current_process = self
        util._finalizer_registry.clear()
        util._run_after_forkers()
        util.info('child process calling self.run()')
        try:
            self.run()
            exitcode = 0
        finally:
            util._exit_function()
    except SystemExit, e:
        if not e.args:
            exitcode = 1
        elif type(e.args[0]) is int:
            exitcode = e.args[0]
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(e.args[0] + '\n')
            sys.stderr.flush()
            exitcode = 1
    except:
        exitcode = 1
        import traceback
        sys.stderr.write('Process %s:\n' % self.name)
        sys.stderr.flush()
        traceback.print_exc()

    util.info('process exiting with exitcode %d' % exitcode)
    return exitcode
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to mess with _bootstrap.  If you are looking for a basic idea on how to use the Process class, I would take a look at:

- http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html
- http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Comment: Thanks Drew - those are excellent intros but I do actually want to figure out what is going on under the bonnet